# What's the default encoding for System.IO.File.ReadAllText

Tags: windows, vb.net, encoding, scite

if we don't mention the decoding what decoding will they use?

I do not think it's `System.Text.Encoding.Default`. Things work well if I **EXPLICITLY** put `System.Text.Encoding.Default` but things go wrong when I live that empty.

So this doesn't work well

```
Dim b = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.txt")
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("test4.txt", b)
```

but this works well

```
Dim b = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("test4.txt", b, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
```

If we do not specify encoding will vb.net try to figure out the encoding from the text file?

Also what is `System.Text.Encoding.Default`?

It's the system default. What is my system default and how can I change it?

How do I know encoding used in a text file?

If I create a new text file and open it with scite I see that the encoding is code page property. What is code page property?

Answer (score 3):

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx), "This method attempts to automatically detect the encoding of a file based on the presence of byte order marks. Encoding formats UTF-8 and UTF-32 (both big-endian and little-endian) can be detected."

Comment: is this the same with encoding.default?

Comment: Nope, this uses the operating system's current ansi code page Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx

Comment: Default seems to be old and not really used anymore/viable. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page

Answer (score 3):

see also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx
This method uses UTF-8 encoding without a Byte-Order Mark (BOM)